# LaTeX places a float in the middle of my script. How do I prevent this?

Tags: floats, listings, positioning

I have a multi-page script in my thesis, and I have used the `listings` package to  format the source code. This works really well, however LaTeX wants to put a float in the middle of this code, which looks bad.

I can use `\clearpage`, and `[H]` to force the offending figure elsewhere, but I think that a more robust solution would be to tell LaTeX not to place floats in the source code.

Can I do something like this?

```
\NoFloatsHere{
   \begin{lstlisting}
       Source Code...
   \end{lstlisting}
}
```

I can't find an option in the listings package to stop the code from being broken by floats.

This question is similar, and the proposed solution "works", but there is nothing stopping LaTeX from placing figures elsewhere in my sourcecode. Is there a better way?

[How to prevent figures from floating 'into' listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82467/how-to-prevent-figures-from-floating-into-listings)

Comment: Insert the floating environment after the `lstlisting`

Comment: Where else in the source code could it appear? If you allow `b` floats then you can similarly set @botnum to 0 at the start of the environment to stop floats appearing at the bottom of the page before the page break. `h'` and `p` should not occur.

Comment: With no MWE, we can't do much better than @egreg's comment. Please give us a bit more to work with!